# Is it possible to create an image slider that fills the content DIV width and height in Orchard CMS?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, slider, orchardcms, flexslider

Orchard CMS has several image sliders and feature item sliders. However all these use image galeries with a fixed width and height.

This works if the site is of a fixed width, but for dynamic sites, where the site can expand both in width and height depending on window size, this doesn't look great.

Is there a way of placing a content slider (e.g. like FlexSlider 2) that fills the whole width and height of the DIV it sits in, while still using Orchard's image gallery features?

Here is an example dynamic layout that would house the flexible Slider:

```
**HEADER** Header Content with dynamic width and fixed height (e.g. 100 pixels)**HEADER**

**CONTENT** slider Content with dynamic width and height **CONTENT**

**FOOTER** Footer Content with dynamic width and fixed height (e.g. of 30 pixels)**FOOTER**
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Orchard looks like a great tool, would be great to use it if only it would play along.

Comment: This looks like 100% a CSS problem, not Orchard. 100% height in CSS is surprisingly trickier than it should be, but a good Google search should give you plenty of information on achieving it.

Comment: Will look at the CSS cheers Bertrand.